# Access, ODBC and PHP slow with WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, odbc, where-clause

I have the following query being executed over DSN via `odbc_connect` in PHP:

```
SELECT Orders.Brand, Orders.AdFolder
  FROM Orders
  LEFT JOIN MPC_Agents ON Orders.UserName = MPC_Agents.UserName
 WHERE  Orders.AdFolder = '$udf'
```

When ran directly in MS Access the result is instantaneous. When ran via `odbc_execute($conn, $query)` it's incredibly slow, but does execute after a while.

When the `WHERE` statement is taken out, it's considerably quicker, despite when ran in the Access SQL console being the same speed as with the `WHERE` statement.

Can anyone help identify the issue?

Comment: Have you got a suitable index?

Comment: @remou correct, please put as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent the entire table being pulled by a query, it is important that you have suitable indexes.

Comment: BTW, why would this not be the case when ran directly inside MS Accesss?

Comment: I am not sure of the details, but MS Access uses the native DAO, which is by far the fastest way to work with MS Access.